# Unable to upload file in ios devices - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem while uploading photos on iPhone in Reactjs app, that photos are not uploaded on iPhone. I put the codes of this component below for better debugging.
I checked my code completely on the computer and everything works perfectly. I also checked this code on Android and it was uploading. But the problem on IOS is still persistent and does not work

```
"use client"
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { set, get } from "local-storage";

const Page = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const loadPhotosFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const uploadsData = JSON.parse(get("uploads")) || [null, null, null];
    const loadedPhotos = uploadsData.map((data, areaIndex) => {
      if (data !== null) {
        return `https://changebazar.chbk.run/api/changebazar/photo/view/${data[0]?.fileName || ""}`;
      }
      return null;
    });

    setPhotos(loadedPhotos);
    setLocalStorageFake(uploadsData);
  };

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([null, null, null]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState([false, false, false]);
  const [localStorageFake, setLocalStorageFake] = useState([null, null, null]);

  const handleDrop = (areaIndex, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    if (!file) {
      console.error("No file dropped.");
      return;
    }

    uploadPhoto(areaIndex, file);
  };

  const handleFileChange = (areaIndex, e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      uploadPhoto(areaIndex, file);
    }
  };

    const uploadPhoto = (areaIndex, file) => {
  setIsLoading((prevLoading) => {
    const newLoading = [...prevLoading];
    newLoading[areaIndex] = true;
    return newLoading;
  });

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  fetch("https://changebazar.chbk.run/api/changebazar/photo", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      "x-auth-token": session?.authToken || "",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setIsLoading((prevLoading) => {
        const newLoading = [...prevLoading];
        newLoading[areaIndex] = false;
        return newLoading;
      });
      const obj = [{ id: data.result.id, fileName: data.result.fileName }];

      const tempLocalStorageFake = [...localStorageFake];
      tempLocalStorageFake[areaIndex] = obj;
      setLocalStorageFake(tempLocalStorageFake);

      setPhotos((prevPhotos) => {
        const newPhotos = [...prevPhotos];
        newPhotos[
          areaIndex
        ] = `https://changebazar.chbk.run/api/changebazar/photo/view/${data.result.fileName}`;
        return newPhotos;
      });

      const updatedLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("uploads")) || [null, null, null];
      updatedLocalStorage[areaIndex] = obj;
      localStorage.setItem("uploads", JSON.stringify(updatedLocalStorage));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};

  const fileInputRefs = [useRef(null), useRef(null), useRef(null)];

  const handleClick = (areaIndex) => {
    fileInputRefs[areaIndex].current.click();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPhotosFromLocalStorage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="row justify-content-center">
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="categories">
          <div className="uploaderWrapper">
            {[0, 1, 2].map((areaIndex) => (
              <div key={areaIndex}>
                <div
                  className="photoBox isLoading"
                  onDrop={(e) => handleDrop(areaIndex, e)}
                  onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                  onDragLeave={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                >
                  <div
                    className={
                      "item dropzone" +
                      (isLoading[areaIndex] ? " isLoading" : "")
                    }
                    onClick={() => handleClick(areaIndex)}
                  >
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      hidden
                      ref={fileInputRefs[areaIndex]}
                      onChange={(e) => handleFileChange(areaIndex, e)}
                    />
                    <div className="loader">
                      <div
                        className={
                          "lds-ring" + (isLoading[areaIndex] ? " active" : "")
                        }
                      >
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={photos[areaIndex] ? "hide" : "show"}>
                      <i className="icon-camera"></i>
                      <h6>انتخاب عکس</h6>
                    </div>
                    <div className={photos[areaIndex] ? "show" : "hide"}>
                      <img src={photos[areaIndex]} alt="" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

          <div className="actions">
            <Link href={{ pathname: "/product/new/" }}>
              <button className="prev">مرحله قبل</button>
            </Link>
            <Link href={{ pathname: "/product/new/description" }}>
              <button className=" next">مرحله بعد</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```